# Clicking an item in selenium by type

Tags: javascript, css, selenium

The element I'm trying to click doesn't have a name or an ID and the class changes each time you refresh the page. The only thing that's consistent in the css is the value. How you do have selenium click the element by the value? It doesnt HAVE to be by value specifically, i just want to click the element.

CSS:

```
<tr class="MuiTableRow-root-799 MuiTableRow-hover-801 _Table-cursor-794" val="4">

<tr class="MuiTableRow-root-799 MuiTableRow-hover-801 _Table-cursor-794" val="4">

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[@val='4']")).click()


driver.findElement(By.css('tr[val="4"]')).click()
```

Changing the wording of val to value wont do anything.

not enough rep to post picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vtzh.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, in [XPath](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) you can select [attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) by using `@` as the prefix for the attribute name:

```
//tr[@val='4']
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [xpath - attribute](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathattribute.php)

Comment: tried driver.findElement(By.css("//tr[@val='4']")).click() and got 'invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified'

Comment: sorry, I did it with xpath instead of by css and got unable to locate element.

Comment: This ended up working when i made selenium wait for the webpage to load, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to click on td based on the value then you have to use the below xpath.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//tr[contains(@class,'MuiTableRow-root')])[1]//td[.='4']")).click()
```

The reason why did not work with the `value` in your xpath is, there is not value property associated with the `tr`.

Comment: 'no such element: Unable to locate element' is the error i got from your code and have kept getting. It doesnt have to be by value though, i just assumed that would be the easiest way

Comment: Try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//tr[contains(@class,'MuiTableRow-root')])[1]")).click()` to make sure the row is located.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[starts-with(@class,'MuiTableRow')][@val='4']"));
    element.click();
```